# jcrop & preview

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jcrop with the preview functionality. It works fine except for the fact that the div which contains the preview image is moved around as I change the selection on the original image.
After a few hours of struggle i'm about to give up :)

Has any one run into this?

thanks,
florin

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was just a CSS gone wrong...

Comment: I know this is old but maybe you can provide more detail in the question and answer?

Comment: I'm not affiliated in any way with the OP but I'm guessing that they didn't put overflow:hidden in their css file pertaining to the crop preview window.